# Order data not dynamic

Tags: virtocommerce

The order data in Virto is not dynamic in the dashboard. It's exactly the same data as shown in the demo version of Virto. Can we change this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

The data is taken from the statistics table in Virto Commerce, that is meant to be updated by a job that runs in the background and gathers the statistics. We will include the job in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

[Virto Commerce 1.11](http://virtocommerce.codeplex.com/releases/view/126088) has been released and this background job is already there.